# App doesn´t find resources in W8 mobile app developed with Sencha Touch and cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-8, sencha-touch

I am working in a Sencha Touch application for the target W8, and after a problems with the inline-content and the next link https://github.com/MsopenTech/winstore-jscompat

I have the next problem in the Visual Studio console

`APPHOST9623` it means resource not found ms-appx-web  question is.. How to solve this? any clue?  With iOS I don´t have this problem and the dependencies should be the same.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which path is failing? Does it work if you switch to `ms-appx`?

Comment: There is not a path is a method.... I don´t understand..

Comment: try to add more details to the question - it's unclear what is happening right now.

Comment: really I don´t know, message in the output console is:  'WWAHost.exe' (Script): Loaded 'Script Code (MSAppHost/2.0)'. 
Unhandled exception at line 1, column 288107 in ms-appx://com.mycompany.survey/www/app.js
0x800c0005 -The program '[5912] WWAHost.exe' has exited with code 3 (0x3).
Activation of the Windows Store app 'com.mycompany.Survey_h35559jr9hy9m!com.mycompany.Survey' failed with error 'Windows was unable to communicate with the target application.  This usually indicates that the target application's process aborted.

Comment: Looks like it's a minified source - what if you [beautify](http://jsbeautifier.org) it and try again? Or is it from the Store crash logs?

Comment: yes it is a minified source but is crashing with a "send" method ... it is not a resource.. is a request (I think so..)

Comment: What does "send" method do? Can you show its source?

Comment: Normally I am developing with Webstorm when is only JS development and with VS2015 to deploy... if I use cordova command line tools in my terminal I have the next error : "Exception to call "ActiveApplication" with the arguments "4" .. any clue??

Comment: Can you provide a full error log including cordova, platforms and plugins versions? You can also add `--verbose` to get more error details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106259/discussion-between-inane-and-daserge).